# Monitor dual intel xeon cpu load?

Tags: linux, monitoring, gentoo, cpu-usage, payload

I have a [Dell 1950 Poweredge](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/1950_specs.pdf) server with two Quad Core Intel Xeon 2.33 GHZ and 16 GB of RAM under Gentoo Linux. I'm running heavy calculation task which I don't know how they were implemented ...

Top gives my partial infos (%CPU, ...) but I don't know if the script is running on the 2 CPUs

I would like to monitor both CPU load/activity (like top does for the entire system) to see if the script takes advatage of the dual CPU or not ?

Except recoding the script, how to optimize the payload for 2 CPU ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running top press the '1' key for per-cpu info.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you've got 2 quad core processors, you've actually got 8 CPUs.

Optimizing serial jobs for parallel processing is a non trivial exercise.

Can you split the calculation into 8 parts and run 8 copies of the script on the separate data ranges?